# C Syslog API - How to Override _PATH_LOG

Tags: c, linux, syslog

I am building something on Linux that includes syslog.h but I want to override the define for _PATH_LOG which currently points to /dev/log

I want the syslog API for this program only to point to a different socket and never send to /dev/log due to some unreasonable constraints imposed by Systemd.  How can I override this define for this build alone?  The define is nested in syslog-path.h which is included by syslog.h, so my program indirectly includes the header which defines this variable.

Comment: What about just tuning journald? I think most rate limits, etc, can be modified.

Comment: are you trying to send your logs to a remote syslog server, rather than to the system logger on the machine that is running your app?

Comment: or are you trying to configure your local machine's logging server to write the logs from your app into a file separate from all of the rest of the system's logs?

Comment: @larsks unfortunately, systemd is absolutely useless in this regard, it allows zero filtering.  It's all or nothing writes to the journal DB https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6432

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I am trying to write to rsyslogd directly via its socket interface and circumvent the systemd-journald database for only this specific program.  Due to security reasons, I cannot have this program logging locally (to the journal, but I want the journal for other things), and rsyslogd is secured properly (unlike the journal), so it must log there due to compliance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you include `syslog.h`, you are using your machine's *system* logger (for example, syslogd).

By design, apps generate syslogs, and the system logging server decides where the logs go. If you want to use the system logger and have your app's logs go to a custom endpoint, you will need to modify your system logging server's configuration. You cannot specify a custom endpoint in code from within your app.

If you want to send syslogs directly from your app to a remote syslog server (bypassing the system logger), you can do that by using a third-party syslog client library.

Comment: I am trying to modify the target socket that the glibc syslog API uses for one specific program.  The syslog daemon shouldn't be impacted, I just wanted the syslog function calls in the glibc syslog API to use a socket other than /dev/log for one application.  This should be orthogonal to the syslog daemon on my system I think.